# COUNT(*) AND LIST OF ITEMS IN COUNT SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this

```
Acct_number    account_id 

xxxx            1111

xxxx            2222

xxxx            3333



SELECT DISTINCT acct_number
      ,count(account_id) 
FROM account_table 
GROUP BY acct_number;
```

How can I make my output be like this:

```
acct_number    count_acct_number    account_id

xxxx                 3             1111, 2222 ,33333
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try below - using `listagg()` function it will work for **11g and higher**

```
SELECT 
    acct_number,count(account_id)
    LISTAGG(account_id, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY account_id) "account_id"
FROM account_table
GROUP BY acct_number
```

OR you can use `wm_concat()` function

```
SELECT acct_number,count(account_id)
       wm_concat(account_id) "account_id"
    FROM account_table
    GROUP BY acct_number
```

Comment: Just a note, i wouldnt recommend wm_concat function as its an undocumented feature. https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques